# QTableView does not respect QAbstractItemModel::span()

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, tree, qt4

I have a tree model representing a k-ary tree (i.e. nodes have a list of children). The model implements the `QAbstractItemModel` and its `QSize span(QModelIndex)` method.

Given the following k-ary tree:

```
      and
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
  or      or
  /\      /\ \
 /  \    /  \ \
I1  I2  I3  I4 I5
```

My intention is to visualize the tree in a `QTableView` from left to right as follows:

```
 ___________
| | | Item 1
| |v|_______
| | | Item 2
| |_|_______
|^| | Item 3
| | |_______
| |v| Item 4
| | |_______
| | | Item 5
|_|_|_______
```

Such that each node spans over all its child nodes.

I've implemented the `QAbstractItemModel::span` method, but it is not taken into account by the `QTableView` class.

When (i.e. reacting to which signal) and how should I rebuild/redraw the `QTableView`?

Notes:

- The model will be a read/write model. The user will have the option to rearrange the expression tree with drag&drop.
- Qt Version 4.8, upgrading to 5 is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt: Implementing span of QAbstractItemModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833415/qt-implementing-span-of-qabstractitemmodel)

Comment: note: in addition, you may also decorate [qabstractitemview::dataChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#dataChanged)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate, because the question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833415/qt-implementing-span-of-qabstractitemmodel] doesn't cover a read/write model. In a read-only model, the spans only need to be set initially.

Comment: this is disturbing [in documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#span): `Note: Currently, span is not used.`

Comment: Well, I've read that comment in the docs. My question is how and when - in terms of signals/slots - should I update the spans?